# Cannot read property 'top' of undefined error only on live server

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

The function below works without errors on my local server but on a live server I get the 'Cannot read property 'top' of undefined' error and the link wont work at all. What is causing that? How can I fix it?

```
    <a class="heroJumpLink" href="#homeStatement"></a>

    <section class="fullCopy homeStatement" id="homeStatement"></section>




        $('.heroJumpLink').on('click',function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var target = this.hash;

            $('html, body').stop().animate({

                'scrollTop': $(target).offset().top -70 + 'px'

            }, 300, 'linear');

        });
```

Comment: Code looks fine.. Is there possibility of your target variable getting manipulated in live server?? Because of any other extra script

Comment: Apparently `$(target)` does not exist so `$(target).offset()` is undefined.  We'd have to see your HTML and see what `this.hash` is to know more.  I'd suggest you insert some `console.log()` statements to check both these variables in your click handler.

Comment: I added the HTML link above

Comment: Console log shows #homeStatement to be target

Comment: But it doesn't log anything on the live server

Comment: Will it log anything whatsoever on your live server? Like `console.log("I'm alive!")`? The code may not be executing because of an error or some other reason.

Comment: No it wont log anything on the liver server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if target exists.

```
$('.heroJumpLink').on('click',function (e) {
//e.preventDefault();
var target = $(this.hash);
target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 70 //offset
        }, 300);
    return false;
}
```

});

Comment: This doesn't show an error but the  href="#homeStatement" link isn't working for some reason

Comment: Actualy It works fine on my local but not the live server

Comment: And now the log is saying #homeStatement" is undefined

Comment: If you inspect the section with the id="homeStatement", is it present in the live server?